# Rewriting a stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I have the following stochastic integral

$$
I(t) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^t (t-s)^2 dW_s 
$$
I wish to rewrite this as a multiple stochastic integral containing only differentials, and I think the following is correct:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^t (t-s)^2 dW(s) = \int_{0}^t \int_{0}^s \int_{0}^z dW_u dz ds,
$$
But I can't prove it. How can I write $I(t)$ as a multiple stochastic integral containing only differentials with respect to time and brownian motion?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @user6247850 Because I want to express the integral using the multiple stochastic integral notation of Kloeden & Pladen.

Comment: @torola . Did my answer help ? If not why not ?

Comment: @kurtG. I think your answer is exactly what I’m looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use
$$
\frac{(t-s)^2}{2}=\int_0^{t-s}u\,du=\int_s^t(u-s)\,du
$$
which gives
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^t (t-s)^2 dW(s)=\int_{0}^t \int_s^t(u-s)\,du\, dW(s)\,.
$$
Stochastic Fubini allows to write the last double integral as
$$
\int_{0}^t \int_0^u(u-s)\, dW(s)\,du\,.
$$
Now you can use
$$
u-s=\int_s^u\,dz
$$
and repeat the exercise.